# Split string by comma, ignoring comma inside string. Am trying CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a string like this:

```
s = '1,2,"hello, there"'
```

And I want to turn it into a list:

```
[1,2,"hello, there"]
```

Normally I'd use split:

```
my_list = s.split(",")
```

However, that doesn't work if there's a comma in a string.

So, I've read that I need to use cvs, but I don't really see how. I've tried:

```
from csv import reader
s = '1,2,"hello, there"'
ll = reader(s)
print ll 
for row in ll:
    print row
```

Which writes:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x020EBC70>

['1']
['', '']
['2']
['', '']
['hello, there']
```

I've also tried with

```
ll = reader(s, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Have you tried a regular expression?

Comment: where did you get that you need to use a csv to split  string?

Comment: @user984003, please accept one or many of the answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is that way because you provide the csv reader input as a string. If you do not want to use a file or a StringIO object just wrap your string in a list as shown below.

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = ['1,2,"hello, there"']
>>> ll = csv.reader(s, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> list(ll)
[['1', '2', 'hello, there']]
```

Comment: You mention StringIO and file but actually use a list in your example. You can use use any iterable there: list or tuple will work just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you probably want to use the `csv` module. To use the reader on a string, you want a `StringIO` object.

As an example:

```
>> import csv, StringIO
>> print list(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(s)))
[['1', '2', 'hello, there']]
```

To clarify, `csv.reader` expects a buffer object, not a string. So `StringIO` does the trick. However, if you're reading this csv from a file object, (a typical use case) you can just as easily give the file object to the reader and it'll work the same way.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! Anyone want to tell me why it was downvoted? It does turn the int into strings, but I'm ok with that.

Comment: You can use use any iterable, actually: list or tuple will work just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually easier to re-use than to invent a bicycle... You just to use [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) properly. If you can't for some reason, you can always check the source code out and learn how's the parsing done there.

Example for parsing a single string into a list. Notice that the string in wrapped in list.

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = '1,2,"hello, there"'
>>> list(csv.reader([s]))[0]
['1', '2', 'hello, there']
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Apparently I wasn't the first with this answer. It's a little weird for me to use SO mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You can split first by the string delimiters, then by the commas for every even index (The ones not in the string)

```
import itertools

new_data = s.split('"')
for i in range(len(new_data)):
    if i % 2 == 1: # Skip odd indices, making them arrays
       new_data[i] = [new_data[i]]
    else:
        new_data[i] = new_data[i].split(",")
data = itertools.chain(*new_data)
```

Which goes something like:

```
'1,2,"hello, there"'
['1,2,', 'hello, there']
[['1', '2'], ['hello, there']]
['1', '2', 'hello, there']
```

But it's probably better to use the csv library if that's what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `ast.literal_eval` if you want to preserve the integers:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('[{}]'.format('1,2,"hello, there"'))
[1, 2, 'hello, there']
```